# Is it possible to get a Kotlin subclass type from within a superclass?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out if something is possible. Generally, what I'm trying to do is get a class type of a subclass from within the companion object of the superclass ... In the snipped below, treat the `__` as what I need

```
companion object
{
    fun fromSnapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot): __
    {
        val model = snapshot.getValue(__)
        model.key = snapshot.key
        // ...
        return model
    }
}
```

Some background ... `DataSnapshot` is from Firebase, and `snapshot.getValue()` takes a `Class<T>`. If I were trying to create an instance of, say, a `TestModel`, code would be as follows

```
companion object
{
    fun fromSnapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot): TestModel
    {
        val model = snapshot.getValue(TestModel::java.class)
        model.key = snapshot.key
        // ...
        return model
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure if what I'm asking is possible in Kotlin. I'm pretty sure it isn't in Java. I hate to mention it, but in Swift, this would be accomplished with what I call "big-S self," or `Self`, which is the class type of instance `self`. If you don't know Swift, `self` is equivalent to Java and Kotlin's `this`.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems to be a very generic function. It doesn't matter what T is and in which companion object this function lives, so I have another version:

```
inline fun <reified T : FirebaseModel> DataSnapshot.toModelOfType() = 
    getValue(T::class.java).also { it.key = this.key}
```

It can be used like this:

```
someSnapshot.toModelOfType<SomeFirebaseModel>()
```

instead of your

```
FirebaseModel.fromSnapshot<SomeFirebaseModel>(someSnapshot)
```

or with imports

```
fromSnapshot<SomeFirebaseModel>(someSnapshot)
```

I prefer mine because it's shorter than your version without imports and more fluent than your version with imports.

<sub>I personally suggest *Prefer extension functions over Java style utility functions*.</sub>

Comment: I love it! Thanks a lot. I'm new to Kotlin but proficient in Java, so I do tend do style things Java-like, but I'm all for preferring Kotlin-style conventions. There needs to be a word for being "Kotlin-y"

Answer (score 1):

Even though I sat on this for days without posting a question, I figured it out less than an hour after posting this question. This can be accomplished with a [reified generic type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), which allows for usage of the generic type from within a function, however these can only be used as `inline` functions. Here's my solution

```
companion object
{
    inline fun <reified T : FirebaseModel> fromSnapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot): T
    {
        val model = snapshot.getValue(T::class.java)
        model.key = snapshot.key
        return model
    }
}
```